# $\sum_i X_i^2$ has $\chi^2_{n}$ distribution and $X_i$ i.i.d. imply $X_i$ normal

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, reference-request, conjectures

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables with distribution $F$. It is known that if $F$ is the standard normal distribution then
$$
S:=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2
$$
has a chi square distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom.

I remeber that the converse is an open problem: if $S$ has a chi square distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom then $F$ has to be the standard normal.

Do you have some references on this problem? (I remember that some instances has been solved, but I couldn't find them anymore)

Comment: Have you looked in Kagan, Linnik, and Rao, _Characterization problems in mathematical statistics_?

Comment: Surely this "open problem" is trivial because folded normal $X_i$ would work as well. I think you mean $X_i^2$ is conjectured to be $\chi_1^2$.

Comment: @kimchilover In p.466 Section "unsolved problem" you can find the following: "Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d. r.v.'s. What can be said about the distribution of $X_1$ if it is known that $\sum X_i^2$ has a chi-square distribution, that $\sum (X_i-\overline{X})^2$ has a chi-square distribution."

Comment: Here you can find the (positive) solution for the case of infinitely divisible random variables: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07362994.2013.817250?journalCode=lsaa20